# Rxjs Nested observer is not executed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observers

I've read a lot of documentation, articles and different thread about how to nest observers in RxJs and Angular, I still missing something and not able to get a result at the end.

#### Here is my code :

**page.ts**

```js
export class LiabilitiesPage implements OnInit {
     constructor(
        private liabilityService: LiabilityService,
        private router: Router
     ) {}

     refreshLiabilities() {
      // Get the liabilities
      console.log('refreshing') // passing there
      this.liabilityService.getAllLiabilities().subscribe(
      (response: Liability[]) => {
        console.log(response); // <=== Never pass there !

        if (response) {
          this.liabilities = response;
        } else {
          // empty response code
        }
      }, error => {
        // response error code (never passing there either)
      }
  }
}
```

**liability.service.ts**

```js
// all the needed imports

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LiabilityService {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    ) {}

  // first try : Do not send the http request
  getAllLiabilities(): Observable<Liability[]> {
    return this.authService.getOptions()
        .pipe(
            tap(options => this.http.get<Liability[]>(this.url + 'me/', options))
        );
  }

    // try 2 : Doesn't work either
    getAllLiabilities(): Observable<Liability[]> {
      return this.authService.getOptions()
        .pipe(
            switchMap(options => this.http.get<Liability[]>(this.url + 'me/', options)), // at this point I tried pretty much every operators (map, mergeMap etc.)
            withLatestFrom()
        ); 
  }
    /* this code was working before that I transformed the authService.getOptions in observable (it was just returning the options synchronyously before)
getAllLiabilities(): Observable<Liability[]> {
  return this.http.get<Liability[]>(this.url + 'me/', this.authService.getOptions());
  }*/
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```js
public getOptions(): Observable<any> {
      return new Observable((observer) => {
          this.storage.get('authToken').then((token) => {
              console.log('passing') // Pass here
              if (token && typeof token.auth_token !== 'undefined') {
                  console.log('passing') // pass here as well
                  this.isLoggedIn = true;
                  this.token = token.auth_token;
              }
              // it is returning the value
              return {
                  headers: this.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token),
                  params: new HttpParams()
              };
          })
      });
    }
```

I tried almost all the possible operator combinations to make it works in the liabilityService without any success.

#### Problem :

The problem is that my `page.ts` subscribes to the `this.http.get<Liability[]>(this.url + 'me/', options)` observer but none xhr request is fired. The http get observer is never executed and I don't understand what I'm missing there.

I'm just starting experimenting Angular, but if I understood correctly the operators should do the mapping and flattening but this looks to never happen.

#### Bonus question :

I'm not catching either why the initial code :

```
return this.http.get<Liability[]>(this.url + 'me/', this.authService.getOptions());
```

is returning an `Observable<Liability[]>`

and with the switchMap :

```
switchMap(options => this.http.get<Liability[]>(this.url + 'me/', options))
```

It is returning a `Observable<HttpEvent<Liability[]>>`

If somebody has a clue and the time to answer me on that, it would be amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in the promise callback `then()`:

```
this.storage.get('authToken').then((token) => {
    return something; // this won't work.
})
```

instead you can use `from`, which will `convert` your promise to an observable.

```
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public getOptions(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.storage.get('authToken')).pipe(map(token => {
        return headers with token.
    }));
}
```

So you could rewrite your code like this:

auth service:

```
private token: string | null = null;


public getOptions(): Observable<any> {
  return this.getToken().pipe(
    map(token => {
      return {
        headers: this.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token),
        params: new HttpParams()
      };
    })
  );
}


private getToken(): Observable<string | null> {
  if (this.token) {
    return of(this.token);
  }

  return from(this.storage.get('authToken')).pipe(
    map(token => token?.authToken || null),
    tap(token => this.token = token)
  );
}
```

then you can use a switchmap:

```
getAllLiabilities(): Observable<Liability[]> {
  return this.authService.getOptions().pipe(
    switchMap(options => this.http.get<Liability[]>(this.url + 'me/', options))
  );
}
```

### Update

The reason for getting `HttpEvent<T>` is because when the overload of `.get()` receives an `any` object it leaves the http event handling entirely up to you.
If you want it to return the provided element type, you have to satisfy the proper overload.
You can achieve that doing it like so:

Instead of returning the entire options, we only return the headers, which should be enough, because we do not really have enough to say about the rest of the options.

**auth service**

```
private token: string | null = null;

public createTokenHeaders(): Observable<HttpHeaders> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
  return addToken(headers);
}

public addToken(headers: HttpHeaders): Observable<HttpHeaders> {
  return this.getToken().pipe(
    map(token => headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + (token || '')))
  );
}

private getToken(): Observable<string | null> {
  if (this.token) {
    return of(this.token);
  }

  return from(this.storage.get('authToken')).pipe(
    map(token => token?.authToken || null),
    tap(token => this.token = token)
  );
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
getAllLiabilities(): Observable<Liability[]> {
  const url = this.url + 'me/';
  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
  return this.authService.addToken(headers).pipe(
    switchMap(updatedHeaders => this.http.get<Liability[]>(url, { headers: updatedHeaders }))
  );
}
```

or:

```
getAllLiabilities(): Observable<Liability[]> {
  const url = this.url + 'me/';
  return this.authService.createTokenHeaders().pipe(
    switchMap(headers => this.http.get<Liability[]>(url, { headers }))
  );
}
```

Note: Make sure you use the headers returned from the call to addToken. Reusing your own instantiated `headers` will not work because setting a header always returns a new `HttpHeaders` object. It is immutable.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bccvd?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This an awesome answer ! Thanks @Silverrmind. Your solution is working but the bonus question remains. TSLint is highlighting the service function return because it considers that the return type is an observable on `HTTPEvent`. We are in the case of my bonus question. Can we avoid that behaviour ? (another way of just changing the getAllLibalities return type)

Comment: @JulienBourdic I've update my answer. Perhaps that makes it clear.

Comment: Sorry for coming back to you this late. I want to thank you again for your time and your crystal clear explanations on how things work ! Hope your answer will help a lot of people. (I've edited your answer to make headers creation only mandatory for pages that need to extend it and to fix a little method visibility issue)

Comment: @JulienBourdic You're welcome. I accepted the edit for the modifier -> public, but I rejected the optional argument. For such cases I would suggested creating an extra method that is called `createTokenHeaders(): Observable<HttpHeaders>`. That can call the addTokenHeader with a newly instantiated headers object. Also I would suggest doing null checks instead of undefined, because null checks catches both undefined and null.

Comment: I get your point. The component service should declare a method in charge to set additional headers and then call the auth service with these. But I don't see any cons to make it optional in the auth service addToken method as these cases will be pretty rare. And thanks for the suggestion. I'm rarely working with Javascript but I thought `null` was considered as an `object` in this language. Which makes the `null !== undefined`. Is it TS which is overiding this behaviour ?

Comment: @JulienBourdic Here is an explanation for null ;) : [How to determine if variable is undefined or null in JavaScript](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null-in-javascript.php)

Comment: @JulienBourdic And about the optional headers: In my opinion the method name should state its intent. If you have this in your code `addToken().subscribe()`, then you read it and you ask yourself, add token to what? To most it is more clear if the parameter is not optional. I have updated my answer with an extra method, which makes it more clear. Again; in my opinion. ;)

Comment: Yeah, that was my point (for the type checks), I will always try to strong type to keep control on how everything is running and avoid un-debuggable side effects. It's just an habit and there is pros and cons to have this approach :). Thanks for the edition (Your idea is really elegant), that was a really instructive and interesting conversation. I'm glad to have created this thread and thankful that you joined it :D